# Change text color of navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the text color of my bootstrap navbar.  How should I go about doing this in css?

To be more specific, I want to change the text color of the labels A, B, C, D.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A really cool title!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
            <li><a id="d.html">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `<a id="d.html" ...` that's not the correct way.  Try a small course in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using less file you can override with variable `@navbar-default-color` and much more thing else.

**Link for navbar variables** : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

You can also **generate a custom bootstrap** version as you need, just read tho official doc here : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 2):

Very basic CSS will do this.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the exact css to change the color?

Comment: that appears to be the exact CSS to target your menu links. Make sure you add the given CSS into your own stylesheet instead of editing the core bootstrap stylesheet.

Comment: @edbert I did post the exact CSS required.

Comment: I will try it again but it didn't work for me before. I added it to my own style sheet

Comment: Your stylesheet needs to be loaded after the bootstrap one.  Also depending on the bootstrap CSS, you may have to use a more specific CSS indentifer such as `.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a`.  Either that, or add an `!important` flag to the color attribute like this `color: red !important;`.  If you use your browser developer tools, it will tell you exactly what CSS is being read and overridden.